# Nodejs querying single data instead of all from mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch data from mongodb's collection. My code is executing only single row data in json format. But when I console log my data I can see all the row data.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AllMinisters  = require('../models/allMinisters');
var db;
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

// Initialize connection once
mongoose.connect("******", { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, database) {
if(err) return console.error(err);
db = database;
// the Mongo driver recommends starting the server here because most apps *should* fail to start if they have no DB.  If yours is the exception, move the server startup elsewhere.
});

exports.getAllMinisters = (req,res,next)=>{
    db.collection("users").find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        docs.each(function(err, doc) {

        if(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers:  { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: doc
                }
                res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        });
    });
};
```

This output in JSON as 
[image]

However the console report shows all
[image]

How can I show all row data in JSON

Comment: Please do add comment if you think the question deserve -ve marking.

Comment: Please do not add any output as screenshots. Add the output directly a formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `docs.each` in your code that will iterate over all the `doc` you get from the `find()` query (which is an array) and inside that `each` block you are sending the response i.e, `res.end(JSON.stringify(response));`, which executes immediately for the first record and hence you get a single object as a response instead of array.

To return the array you need to put `res.end(JSON.stringify(response));` outside the `each()` loop with `toArray` function. You can even remove the `each()` loop if that is not required. So, your code will be something like:

```
exports.getAllMinisters = (req, res, next)=>{
  db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {return next(err);}
    docs.each(function (err, doc) {
      if (doc) {
        //code for single doc
        console.log(doc);
      }
    });
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried using `res.next` which seems not working. Can you help me fixing it please

Comment: @Santosh let me know if you are still struggling

Comment: That `body:doc` is empty right ? its not working still even after changing it to docs

Comment: @Santosh oops, I missed the header. See now. It should work

Comment: It shows error like ` Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179302/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-santosh).